# I can not activate a new user with the url in mail. Page not found

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

When I register a new user :
- I receive a mail with activation link to activate this new user
- I tested in localhost and it works
- Deploy on production
- I tested and the link in production but it didn't find page

I updated my application-prod.yml application-dev.yml to receive the mails.

I changed my app.yml to remove the port 8080 in production with :

```
ports:
    - 80:8080
```

My app.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
    mariage-app:
        image: mylogin/mariage
        environment:
            - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mariage-mysql:3306/mariage?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
        ports:
            - 80:8080
    mariage-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: mariage-mysql
´´´



My application-prod.yml
´´´

# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuration overrides the application.yml file.
#
# More information on profiles: https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/
# More information on configuration properties: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================

logging:
    level:
        ROOT: INFO
        ch.ricreate.mariage: INFO
        io.github.jhipster: INFO

spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mariage?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
        username: username
        password: password
        hikari:
            poolName: Hikari
            auto-commit: false
            data-source-properties:
                cachePrepStmts: true
                prepStmtCacheSize: 250
                prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
                useServerPrepStmts: true
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        database: MYSQL
        show-sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: mariage
            hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
            hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
    liquibase:
        contexts: prod
    mail:
        host: smtp.mymail.ch
        port: 587
        username: mymail@mymail.ch
        password: password
        tls: true
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.mymail.ch
    thymeleaf:
        cache: true

# ===================================================================
# To enable TLS in production, generate a certificate using:
# keytool -genkey -alias mariage -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
#
# You can also use Let's Encrypt:
# https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm
#
# Then, modify the server.ssl properties so your "server" configuration looks like:
#
# server:
#    port: 443
#    ssl:
#        key-store: classpath:config/tls/keystore.p12
#        key-store-password: password
#        key-store-type: PKCS12
#        key-alias: mariage
#        # The ciphers suite enforce the security by deactivating some old and deprecated SSL cipher, this list was tested against SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
#        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
# ===================================================================
server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
        min-response-size: 1024

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
    http:
        version: V_1_1 # To use HTTP/2 you will need SSL support (see above the "server.ssl" configuration)
        cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
            timeToLiveInDays: 1461
    cache: # Cache configuration
        hazelcast: # Hazelcast distributed cache
            time-to-live-seconds: 3600
            backup-count: 1
            management-center: # Full reference is available at: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.9/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html
                enabled: false
                update-interval: 3
                url:
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
                # As this is the PRODUCTION configuration, you MUST change the default key, and store it securely:
                # - In the JHipster Registry (which includes a Spring Cloud Config server)
                # - In a separate `application-prod.yml` file, in the same folder as your executable WAR file
                # - In the `JHIPSTER_SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION_JWT_BASE64_SECRET` environment variable
                base64-secret: MY BASE  64 KEY...
                # Token is valid 24 hours
                token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
                token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: mymail@mymail
        base-url: http://www.mydomain.ch
    metrics:
        logs: # Reports metrics in the logs
            enabled: false
            report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queue-size: 512

# ===================================================================
# Application specific properties
# Add your own application properties here, see the ApplicationProperties class
# to have type-safe configuration, like in the JHipsterProperties above
#
# More documentation is available at:
# https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

# application:
```

I have this error messages :

3www.mydomain.ch/:13 GET http://www.mydomain.ch/main.3f34c02a7b8ec7cd9bd5.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://www.mydomain.ch/styles.676f69d3635eaaafa540.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2www.mydomain.ch/:13 GET http://www.mydomain.ch/polyfills.9d3a8743be9f041e6ba8.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the template `templates/mail/activationEmail.html` ?

Comment: No, but the URL in the is not the problem. It send me to the page but the page is always blank.